# egrep with a filemask

Tags: terminal, grep

How can i alter this command to only search through .tpl and .php files within the underlying directory structure?

```
egrep "\[#([^]])+#\]|_t?\(([^\)])+\)|\{_t ([^\}])+\}" . -RohiIs | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find), e.g.

`$ find . \( -name \*.tpl -o -name \*.php \) -exec egrep <flags> <expression> {} \; | sort | uniq`